# Python парсинг с авторизацией

Tags: python, парсер, requests

Пытаюсь парсить информацию о своём персонаже в браузерной игре.
Для этого нужно залогинится. Как это сделать?
Пишу такой вот код:

```
import requests

URL = "https://tiwar.ru/?sign_in=1"

r = requests.post(URL, data={"login": "NickName", "pass": "MyPass"})
print(r.text)
```

Выдает код страницы с вводом логина и пароля:

```
<input class='text medium-text' type='text' id='login' name='login' value="NickName"/><br/>Пароль:<br/><input class='text medium-text' type='password' name='pass'/>
```

Заметил, что в **input** для **login** есть по умолчанию **value** со значением "", а у пароля нет, думаю в этом проблема. Как можно заполнить?

P.S. Пришел к такому выводу, так как в другой игре есть значения и для логина и пароля по умолчанию и я могу парсить данные своего персонажа при точно таком же коде:

```
import requests

URL = "https://s7-ru.bitefight.gameforge.com/user/lobbylogincheck"  # Парсится без проблем с авторизацией

r = requests.post(URL, data={"user": "NickName", "pass": "MyPass"})
print(r.text)
```

Comment: вам нужна библиотека Selenium

Comment: Можете сказать, что именно нужно найти в документации по Selenium? Варианты с ней в гугле тоже выпадали, но ничего не нашел, оставил самый простой код, который хоть на треть, но работает.

Comment: по аналогии думаю разберетесь  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Houj1Ult3Vk  и мой стандартный совет: если плохо находятся html элементы с помощью стандартных методов библиотеки - используйте javascript. js код можно запускать через selenium. как найти html javascript гуглится на раз. Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я как раз уже к этому моменту вошёл, долго искал как на кнопку нажать, нажимал постоянно не на ту, что надо.

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено с помощью Selenium. Спасибо **Zhenia Kviatkivskyi**.

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = Service(executable_path="C:/Users/User/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=chromedriver)
browser.get('https://tiwar.ru/?sign_in=1')

username = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'login')
password = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'pass')
entry = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input.label')
username.send_keys("NickName")
password.send_keys("MyPass")
entry.click()

time.sleep(3)
print(entry)
```